# Why do Qing Dynasty coins frequently have cinnabar rubbed into them?

Tags: ancient-history, numismatics

I collect Chinese coins. I would really like to know, why do Qing Dynasty coins frequently have cinnabar rubbed into them? I know the mystical properties of cinnabar or “dragon blood”, but if it was done for ritual/magical reasons it just seems odd you never see it on more ancient Chinese coins, but only the more recent Qing ones. Or was Qing society just more saturated with magic/sorcery than any other period in Chinese history? This seems unlikely.

I could provide many pictures, but I’m not sure I can do it as a guest. I can find no references really, other than very general implications - that is why I ask the question! I have acquired all my “cinnabar” smeared coins from a reliable international dealer, who just refers to it as “ancient cinnabar” meaning it is contemporary with the coin‘s production. I have asked him about this and he just said coins were often used in rituals and celebrations. What makes it curious is that as I said you never see it on more ancient coins. I am curious as to whether it is everyday ritual or sorcery.

As an example of why it seems strange, the Tang Kai Yuan was particularly favored for magic etc., but I have never seen one with cinnabar.

Comment: Quick web search reveals zero records of Qing dynasty coins with cinnabar.  I'm not challenging you, but it would help to research if we understood a bit more. Do you have any pictures? Any references to the practice? Have you done any research? Is it merely that the cinnabar has worn off the older coins?

Comment: The Qing dynasty was known to be particularly drenched in superstition and sorcery).

Comment: please don't comment; update the question with the information.  The more comments a question has, the lower the chance of a useful/accepted answer. I've copied your comments into the question & deleted the comments; you may wish to revise the question for clarity/style. On the other hand, if you can provide a URL to an image, I'll be happy to include it in the question.

Comment: I am not a chemist, nor do I know much about about numastics or anything about the Qing dynasty but I seem to remember that mercury can be used to polish silver, removing the tarnish and [in the process forming cinnabar](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/x93ur/how_does_mercury_polish_silver/).  Are the coins you are interested in silver?  If so cinnabar may be a byproduct.